# I do not understand how to add multiple SSH for github using ssh config

Tags: git, macos, github, ssh, openssh

I'm on an M1 Macbook Pro 16" if this information matters at all.

Here is a list of things I did !AFTER! removing the contents of the config file.

```
$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

I have created a simple ssh file using the recommended type:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my.actual.email@whatever.com" -f github-personal
... password, whatever

$ ls -la
.
..
bkup
config
github-personal
github-personal.pub
known_hosts
```

I then procede to add the public key to my account

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/github-personal.pub | pbcopy
```

Go to my account, settings, SSH and GPG, add the key, give it a relevant name.

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

Good, as expected

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/github-personal
password:...

$ ssh-add -l
256 SHA256: ... my.email@whatever
```

compare the signature with that on github, yes it's the same, everything works.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi [my-name]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

$ git clone git@github.com:my-user/my-repo
cloning into ... whatever it works
```

Nice! The bare minimum works! Now let's try having 3 github accounts, each with it's own SSH key. But ... that's scary. Let's get the exact above thing to work with a config file before even adding other accounts maybe?

```
contents of ~/.ssh/config:

AddKeysToAgent yes
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host personal-github
    HostName github.com
    User git # as instructed by git, only ever use the git user i.e. git@github.com
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-personal
#    PreferredAuthentications publickey,password
```

I had no idea if `PreferredAuthentications publickey,password` was messing me up, I tried with and without it. Now without.

```
$ ssh-add -l
yes, agent still has it, it's listed here

$ ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

...

```
$ ssh-add -D
$ ssh-add -l
key not longer here

$ ssh personal-github
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi my-name! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.

$ ssh-add -l
yep, key was added automatically
```

So, maybe here I'm missing something. I understand the following: I define in the config file a `Host name-defined-by-me`. This starts a function of sorts, or whatever, namespace, don't care. Where I can keep defining parameters until the next `Host name-defined-by-me-2` comes up.

Then I call that `name-defined-by-me` to load that particular configuration.

In my case, let's go over the file again:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host personal-github
    HostName github.com
    User git # as instructed by git, only ever use the git user i.e. git@github.com
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-personal
#    PreferredAuthentications publickey,password
```

I have defined globally that I want:

- To automatically add keys to the agent
- But only specifically identified keys, not everything in ~/.ssh/
- And - I THINK - only when I call `ssh name-defined-by-me` or here `ssh personal-github`

In the specific host section of `personal-github`, I am saying that the HostName of whom I am trying to connect to is github.com, with the User `git` forming `git@github.com`.

I want to use my mac Key Chain to not provide the password every time I change the host. (I'd probably need a `$ ssh-add -D` between host changes). And I'm specifying the singular file I want to add.

It does add the file when I call `$ssh personal-github`, it doesn't ask for my password, and github responds with my name so SOMETHING must be right.

Yet, I cannot continue past that point.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

$ rm -rf my-repo
$ git clone git@github.com:my-user-name/my-repo
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm at a loss.

Comment: You need `IdentitiesOnly yes`. Otherwise `IdentitiesFile` is just a suggestion.

Comment: @torek I I know. That’s why I’ve added ‘IdentitiesOnly yes’ and made sure to point out in my post that I have already done so.

Comment: Ah, I scanned too fast, and missed that you had set it globally (I assume that works but I've never tried it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

That is expected.
Whenever you are referencing a private key in your ~/.ssh/config file, under an entry `Host key1`, you need to change your URL to

```bash
ssh -Tv key1
git clone key1:me/myRepository
```

And you can repeat that for `key2`, `key3`, ...

Comment: That did it, and it also makes perfect sense. Yet, for the life of me, I have no idea how I was supposed to figure this out myself. Those man pages are dreadful. That being said, thank you.